# Apuntadores con el tipo float en C

Tags: c, float, linux-mint

Este problema no me deja dormir (me podrían dar un tip para poder resolverlo, por favor):

Escribir un programa que lea dos valores de tipo float, y luego realice la suma de los dos, pero sin usar directamente una escritura de la forma a + b, sino que use apuntadores estos.

Comment: Aquí tienes un tip: [edit] tu pregunta y añadir que es lo que te está dando problemas, y añade el código que has intentado. Te aseguro que yo voy a dormir bien aunque no entregues el ejercicio a tiempo, por lo que si precisas de ayuda, deberás de ver como [ask], y ya de paso te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Comment: Imagino que antes de pedirte ese ejercicio te habrán explicado qué es un puntero y cómo se usa, y quizás hasta te hayan dado apuntes al respecto. Yo comenzaría por leerlos para entender los conceptos. Una vez comprendidos verás que lo que te piden no es en absoluto difícil. Si tienes alguna dificultad concreta con algún concepto o con código que hayas escrito y no haya funcionado como esperabas, crea una pregunta para ello

Comment: Las pregunta viene en el libro de Introducción a la programación de la autora Mihaela Juganaru Mathieu; viene al final del capítulo: apuntadores, funciones y recursividad.
Ya resolví varios de los ejercicios de apuntadores.
Yo más o menos pienso que podría resolverse usando aritméticaa en hexadecimal, ya que las direcciones están en esa base, o algo así, no? La pregunta viene tal cual el libro, sólo que al final se me olvidó poner: sino que use apuntadores para estos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los punteros no tienen nada qué ver con aritmética hexadecimal como sugieres en un comentario. La única relación es que para imprimir el valor de un puntero se suele usar la cadena de formato `"%p"`, la cual vuelca en hexadecimal ese valor. Pero en realidad el valor del puntero no es más que un número, al margen del formato con que se imprima.

Ese número representa la dirección de memoria en la que se halla otra variable. Se dice entonces que el puntero **apunta** a esa dirección de memoria.

Para trabajar con punteros tienes que tener en cuenta tres fases:

1. Declaración del puntero
2. Inicialización del puntero
3. Uso del puntero.

#### Declaración

Es tan simple como poner un `*` delante del nombre de la variable que estás declarando. Así, si quieres un puntero que *apunte* a datos de tipo float basta poner:

```
float *mi_puntero;
```

#### Inicialización

Como cualquier otra variable, por el hecho de declararla no se le da un valor inicial (aunque algunos compiladores le dan el valor 0 a las variables no inicializadas, no es buena práctica suponer que siempre sea así pues algunos compiladores no lo hacen).

Si no lo has inicializado, es posible que el puntero contenga un número aleatorio. Puedes comprobarlo imprimiendo su valor con `printf("%p\n", mi_puntero)`. Si ves "(nil)" es que se ha inicializado con el valor 0, pero si ves cualquier otro número hexadecimal es que no se ha inicializado y por tanto apunta a una dirección aleatoria.

Un puntero no inicializado no debe usarse, pues los efectos son imprevisibles (lo más probables es que el programa rompa y deje de ejecutarse, pero pueden pasar cosas peores). Por tanto ¿Cómo inicializar un puntero?

Hay dos formas correctas y una incorrecta (que comento de todas formas para que lo veas):

1. Darle un valor directamente, con algo como `mi_puntero = 5000`. Esta es la forma incorrecta pues estás haciendo que el puntero apunte directamente a una dirección elegida por ti, en este caso 5000, pero no sabes qué hay en esa dirección por lo que es peligroso tratar de usarla. Lo más probable es que esa dirección esté protegida por el operativo y al tratar de usarla se produzca un error.
2. Darle la dirección en la que se encuentre otra variable. Por ejemplo, supón que tienes una variable (que tiene que ser de tipo `float` en este caso) llamada `b`. La dirección de esa variable se obtiene con el operador `&` por lo que puedes hacer:

   ```
   float b = 3.1416;  // Le damos un valor inicial a b
   mi_puntero = &b;
   ```

   En este caso el puntero apunta a la dirección donde está `b` por lo que se suele decir directamente que **el puntero apunta a `b`**
3. Llamando a `malloc()` (esto se denomina asignación dinámica de memoria). No voy a entrar en detalles de este método pues se sale de los objetivos de la pregunta. Pero que sepas que es la forma de "crear" variables nuevas mientras el programa se está ejecutando, sin necesidad de declararlas previamente. Estas "variables" no tienen nombre, sólo direcciones en las que se hallan, y por tanto la única forma de trabajar con ellas es mediante punteros.

#### Usar el puntero

Una vez tienes el puntero apuntando a una dirección, puedes manipular el dato que hay en esa dirección poniendo el operador `*` delante del puntero.

Sí, el operador `*` sirve para varias cosas en C. Además de ser el operador de multiplicación, es también como vimos antes el que declara que una variable es de tipo puntero, y vemos ahora que además es el que permite acceder al valor apuntado.

Así, ya que teníamos que `mi_puntero` apuntaba a `b`, tendremos que `*mi_puntero` accederá al *valor* de `b`. Podemos acceder a ese valor solo para consultarlo, por ejemplo para imprimirlo:

```
printf("Valor del puntero: %p. Valor apuntado: %f\n", mi_puntero, *mi_puntero);
```

Observa cómo al poner `mi_puntero` lo que consultamos es el valor que hay dentro del puntero (y lo imprimo con `"%p"`) mientras que al poner `*mi_puntero` lo que consultamos es lo que hay en la dirección a la que apunta el puntero. En este caso observaríamos el valor 3.1416, ya que ese es el valor de `b`.

No sólo podemos consultar ese valor, sino también *cambiarlo*, si usamos `*mi_puntero` al lado izquierdo de una asignación, por ejemplo así:

```
*mi_puntero = 2.17;
```

de este modo cambiamos lo que hay en la dirección a que apunta. ¡Cuidado, ya que el puntero apuntaba a `b`, acabamos de cambiar el valor de `b`!

Esto es lo básico que necesitas saber sobre punteros para responder al ejercicio.

### Solución

No voy a darte el código, para que lo intentes por ti mismo, pero entiendo que la idea del ejercicio sería:

1. Declara un par de variables de tipo `float`, digamos `a` y `b`.
2. Declara un par de variables de tipo *puntero a float*.
3. Inicializa los punteros para que uno apunte a `a` y el otro a `b`.
4. Escribe una expresión que calcule el resultado de `a+b`, pero sin usar las variables `a` y `b`, sino usando los punteros en su lugar. Recuerda poner un `*` delante de cada puntero para acceder al valor apuntado.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Estuvo muy clara tu explicación